# Is the Uniswap v2 0.3% trading fee calculated wrong?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, amm

I am digging into the details of how the [token swapping fee](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/advanced-topics/fees/) is calculated and I cannot get a formula that reproduces the expected 0.3% fee.

Let's say there's a USDT-ETH pool with:

- 1000 USDT
- 10 ETH
- k = 1000*10 = 10,000

Now let's imagine you swap 300 USDT for ETH.

If there was no fee, then you should get ETH 2.3076923077 (300/1300 * 10).

If we add 0.3% fee, then you'll get ETH 2.3007692308 (0.997 * 2.3076923077)

However, in the Uniswap way, they actually get the amount out assuming only 99.7% of 300 = 299.1 USDT is deposited in (this can be seen [here](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/dda62473e2da448bc9cb8f4514dadda4aeede5f4/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L43-L50)).

Using this method, user gets 299.1/1299.1 * 10 = 2.3023631745 ETH.

And this amount is actually 2.3023631745/2.3076923077 * 100 = 99.769% of the amount if no swap fee is applied.

Which means the swap fee amounts to 0.23% instead.

Am I applying the correct logic to determine the token swapping fee?

Comment: The 0.3% as referenced in the documentation applies to the amount that you trade in. You have successfully demonstrated that in the above write up. 0.23% is the impact of the trade, but... the fee is still 0.3% on the value that you trade in.